# Anaconda dependencies

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies, anaconda

I recently installed ipython, and along with it, anaconda.  However, anaconda changed my sys.path directories, and some of the packages I was using before stopped working.  Even after uninstalling anaconda using pip, it seems that those directories remained.  How do I change them back?  When I enter the python shell, I do and see the following:

[image]

Comment: How did you uninstall anaconda using pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda installs its own Python. When you run that Python, it uses the Anaconda Python libraries. The Anaconda installer put a line in your `.profile` that makes it first in the PATH, so that when you type `python`, it loads the Anaconda Python.

If you want to use the Python packages that you had installed into another Python with Anaconda, you will need to install them, using `conda` (or `pip` if they are not available via `conda`)

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is a separate python environment and as such doesn't have access to anything you installed in the base python environment. Depending on the project is usually a good idea to have separate environments using virtualenv or a similar tool. You can also do this using Anconda as described below.

1. Create a virtual environment for your project

   `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`
2. Activate your virtual environment

   `source activate yourenvname`
3. Install additional Python packages to a virtual environment.

   `conda install -n yourenvname [package]`

Full description can be found at http://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: As I didn't downvote, I can't remove the downvote either, so just hope someone else found this answer helpful and votes it up.